# What would be an alternative to Robogebra to animate mathematical writing?

Tags: math-software, online-resources

Yesterday, I came across a website called [Robogebra](https://www.robogebra.com/app). It does exactly what I wanted: It creates animations simulating the handwriting of mathematical equations, it supports LaTeX syntax and does many other interesting things in terms of presentations. It also has some sort of CAS built in.

However, it is very poorly docummented (almost not at all) and it actually appears to be a dead project. It would be a shame to start working with this tool only to see it disappear overnight.

What would be an alternative to this? I want mostly the handwriting animation effect and it has to be something with plenty of support for mathematical equations.

Comment: That Link doesn’t work very well on iPhone 7. Maybe also cross-post this question on Stackoverflow?